# Convert and update continuous serial port communication from Arduino to an integer array in Visual Studios (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int

I am currently reading data coming in continuously from an i2c sensor connected to an Arduino and capturing the data successfully in Visual Studios. The sensor is getting 4 different X, Y values and then sends them via Serial.Print in the format of:

X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,X4,Y4 (Where X1 - X4 and Y1 - Y4 are values that range betwen 0-1023 i.e., 1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023) which is then followed up with a Serial.println("") command. This whole process is repeated continuously until turned off. Arduino code:

```
for (i=0;i<16;i++) { data_buf[i]=0; }
    i=0;
      while(Wire.available() && i < 16) {
        data_buf[i] = Wire.read();
        i++;
      }

     Ix[0] = data_buf[1];
     Iy[0] = data_buf[2];
     s = data_buf[3];
     //Ix[0] += (s & 0x30) <<4;
     Ix[0] = data_buf[1] | ((data_buf[3] >> 4) & 0x03) << 8;
     Iy[0] = data_buf[2] | ((data_buf[3] >> 6) & 0x03) << 8;
     //Ix[0] = Ix[0] / test;

     Ix[1] = data_buf[4];
     Iy[1] = data_buf[5];
     s = data_buf[6];
     Ix[1] += (s & 0x30) <<4;
     Iy[1] += (s & 0xC0) <<2;

     Ix[2] = data_buf[7];
     Iy[2] = data_buf[8];
     s = data_buf[9];
     Ix[2] += (s & 0x30) <<4;
     Iy[2] += (s & 0xC0) <<2;

     Ix[3] = data_buf[10];
     Iy[3] = data_buf[11];
     s = data_buf[12];
     Ix[3] += (s & 0x30) <<4;
     Iy[3] += (s & 0xC0) <<2;

      for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
if (Ix[i] < 1000)
Serial.print("");
if (Ix[i] < 100)
Serial.print("");
if (Ix[i] < 10)
Serial.print("");
    Serial.print( int(Ix[i]) );
Serial.print(",");
if (Iy[i] < 1000)
Serial.print("");
if (Iy[i] < 100)
Serial.print("");
if (Iy[i] < 10)
Serial.print("");
Serial.print( int(Iy[i]) );
if (i<3)
Serial.print(",");
}


Serial.println("");
delay(15);
}
```

What I'm have problems with, is converting those values from within Visual Studios so that I can pass on the data as individual integer values. What I have now:

```
void _spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Using this.Invoke causes deadlock when closing serial port, and BeginInvoke is good                      practice anyway.
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved), new object[] { sender, e });
                return;
            }

            int maxTextLength = 1000; // maximum text length in text box
            if (tbData.TextLength > maxTextLength)
                tbData.Text = tbData.Text.Remove(0, tbData.TextLength - maxTextLength);

            // This application is connected to a Arduino sending ASCCI characters, so data is converted                to text
            string Rawstr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);

            //Get values that are between the ',' from e.Data and store them in our new array
            string[] str = Rawstr.Split(',');

            //Convert str array into new int[] array (or similar) I've tried multiple things with no success
              ??????
             //This results in a "Input string was not in a correct format" error.
            int xx = Convert.ToInt32(str[0]);

            tbData.AppendText(Rawstr);
            tbData.ScrollToCaret();

        }
```

This is where I am currently stuck. I believe I have an issue where pretty much an infant number of values are going into the string[] str because I don't have a limit on it before it starts to put new values into/and replacing the string values already in it.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The string "X1,Y1,X2,Y2," needs to become an integer array [1,1,2,2]?

Comment: That's the ultimate goal, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq.
First split on `,`, skip the empty and whitespace characters, then trim of the first character (X or Y) and convert the remaining part to an integer.

```
String Rawstr = "x1,y1,x2,y2," + Environment.NewLine;
Int32[] integers = Rawstr.Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None).Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(1))).ToArray();
```

For `"x1,y1,x2,y2,"` you get an integer array containing `[1,1,2,2]`.

Comment: I'm still getting a "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format" error.

Comment: On the code in my answer? Can you show the string value on which it fails?

Comment: To clarify, the x1,y1,x2,y2, format is being sent from the Arduino. This is program is collecting incoming data from System.IO.Ports commands and then the conversion is happening (or trying to make happen)

Comment: Now you show a pending `,` in the csv string. I have updated my answer to take care of that. Please run the code as in the answer, as it shouldn't matter where the csv string comes from.

Comment: @ryano I might have missed the part of the linefeed character at the end, but fixed that in my answer.

Comment: I've included the Arduino code above for your reference. I think my issue might be the initial serial read command. It appears as if the first part of the string isn't the data that I'm looking for. i.e.,  "⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮23,1023,700,...." etc. My baud rate is set correctly so I'm not sure why the string starts with the strange text.

Comment: Seems why it is quite hard to get an answer to your question. If the csv string would be in X1,Y1,X2,Y2 format, you would be fine by now :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on how I wrote this up. My values don't literally have "X" or "Y" in front of them. They come through as values from 0-1023 (i.e., 1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023,1023). The issue right now, it appears, is that my string looks like this at the beginning of the serial read instead of the format it should be in "JH?J??)JH?JH?JH?j??)JH?JH?JH?J??)JeH?JH?JH?(J?JH?JD?)JH?JH?JH?J??)J(?JH?JH?J??)JH?JH?JH?J??)JH?JH?JH?j??)JH?JH?JH?J??)JeH?JH?JH?(J??)JH?J(????b????b????j
023"

Comment: No prob. It might be better to just start a new question, when you have the input string figured out. Otherwise this all might get quite confusing.

Comment: I agree with that